# Angular: Display sitemap generated from API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, sitemap

I have an Angular app and some dotnet Web APIs. For SEO purposes I need to serve sitemaps from within my Angular app via Url e.g. https://myapp.com/sitemap

The sitemap itself is generated and served by one of the APIs (e.g. https://api1.com/sitemap) and delivers the complete sitemap back.

In the google webmaster tools you are only allowed to add sitemap links from the current domain, in my case https://myapp.com.

At the moment I struggle on how to add a route like https://myapp.com/sitemap to my routes.ts to serve the sitemap from the API **only**, with no other content of the Angular app.

**Edit: .htcaccess of the webserver for my Angular app**

```
# This is for other websites in webserer dir which uses php
AddType application/x-httpd-php71 .php

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=admin.kombas.de
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Sitemap: Need rewrite for https://kombas.de/sitemap
RewriteRule "^/sitemap" "https://kombasapicontent.azurewebsites.net/api/data/sitemap" [L,P]
#RewriteRule ^/sitemap https://kombasapicontent.azurewebsites.net/api/data/sitemap [L,P] # No quotes make no difference
#RewriteRule "sitemap" "https://kombasapicontent.azurewebsites.net/api/data/sitemap" [L,P] # Only visible reaction => The requested URL was not found on this server.

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Somehow I don't get any rewrite to work.

Answer (score 0):

generating the sitemap using javascript may be possible but not the best way to do this (its slow and unneded overhead for the crawler to run your angular app). 
If you want to generate the sitemap on api, you can deliver it directly without any use of javascript framework involved. You can configure the /sitemap route to any api controller with rewrite rules of your webserver, e.g. rewrite `/sitemap to /api/sitemap`

Comment: As far as my researches say, this is not possible, the way you wrote it:

`{ path: 'sitemap',
    redirectTo: '/api/sitemap',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },`


works for internal urls / routes of the app only - not for externals and my API is an external Url.

Comment: Ah sorry, you meant on the webserver directly. I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: I edited my initial post, because I don't get any rewrite to work with this htaccess on my webserver (Apache) for my Angular app.

Comment: is your api running on another domain than your frontend? Then you'll need to reverseproxy the request.
try `RewriteRule    "^/sitemap"  "https://api1.com/sitemap"  [P]` before the last line

Comment: No, it's not working. I am still landing within my Angular app on the error-component which is defined in my routes.ts like`{ path: '**', component: ErrorComponent}`. And yes, the API is running on another domain within Azure.

Comment: sry, it should be `RewriteRule "^/sitemap" "https://api1.com/sitemap" [L,P]` with L so it does stop processing rewrites if this rule match

Comment: Unfortunately no, I edited to show my production .htaccess with the real Urls, so you can see by yourself.

Comment: ok, i needed to install some apache to test this...
The correct line is `RewriteRule "^sitemap" "https://kombasapicontent.azurewebsites.net/api/data/sitemap" [L,P]`

Also make sure, you enable `proxy_http_module` in httpd.conf and add the directive `SSLProxyEngine On` to your virtualhost config, otherwise it won't work

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. I need to discuss this with my hoster.

Comment: why dont host the angular app in azure, too?

Comment: Have my domain at my hoster for over 10 years now and I don't know so far what to do to host / transfer the domain to Azure. This might be something for the next steps. I just relaunched parts of the whole website (the "homepage") technically. Rest follows.